# Dashes in lists

Tags: punctuation, lists, dashes

As a mathematician I often have to explain the notation in my writing. For example, I write:

"F denotes my favourite function, A - a beautiful set and K - an important kernel."

Should I use dashes as above, omit them, replace them by a colon? I can't find an answer anywhere...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question, however, is largely a matter of style; there is no single standard for right or wrong. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: Colons don't work at all. Dashes are fine. However, you're not actually using dashes. You're using hyphens. And that is quite wrong indeed. Especially for a mathematician. You wouldn't use the symbols b, d, p, and q interchangeably just because they look kinda similar. Or write n instead of π. Likewise, you should know and understand the difference between a hyphen, an en dash, an em dash, and a minus. These are all different, and they all mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop the dashes entirely. I don't think any style guide would endorse them. As an editor, I would change the punctuation this way:

"F denotes my favourite function, A a beautiful set, and K an important kernel"

or

"F denotes my favourite function; A, a beautiful set; and K, an important kernel"

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, is there any source you could point me to? Or is the answer based on your editorial experience?

Comment: Technically, it's the second sentence that's more "correct," in which the commas act as placeholders for *denotes*. The non-elided version of the sentence would be: *F denotes my favourite function, A denotes a beautiful set, and K denotes an important kernel.* That full version will always be correct. But shortening it makes it read better. While the first version doesn't use commas (as it should), it might still be a more stylistic choice for those who don't like the use of semicolons. You could also use *A* ***is*** *a beautiful set, and K* ***is*** an important kernel.